# Google maps wont display on mobile after using Phonegap Build

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I have Google maps working fine in Firefox, however when i build it for mobile. The map simply doesn't display or load, sadly my coding experience and knowledge is zilch and still haven't found a solution... Does anyone have any pointers as to what the issue is? I can post more code if needed

```
var map, places, iw;
var markers = [];
var autocomplete;
var defaultLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(34.0983425, -118.3267434); 
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.783259, -122.402708);

function initialize() {
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 17,
    //center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    browserSupportFlag = true;
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      initialLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords
        .latitude, position.coords.longitude);
      map.setCenter(initialLocation);
      map.setZoom(16);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: initialLocation,
        title: "You are here!"
      });
      marker.setMap(map);
    }, function() {
      handleNoGeolocation(browserSupportFlag);
    });
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
    myOptions);
  places = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'tilesloaded', tilesLoaded);
  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById(
    'autocomplete'));
  google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
    showSelectedPlace();
  });
}
```

Comment: Sounds to me like you haven't whitelisted it in your `config.xml` file. Try adding this to the config... `<access origin="*"/>` this will let your app reach out to external resources. I would recommend configuring the origin part though to something more specific. Make sure you add the cordova whitelist plugin too, see the Github docs... https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist#network-request-whitelist

Answer (score 0):

you need to use "plugin" before initializing

ie: plugin.google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas");

similar for other initializations

```
var map, places, iw;
var markers = [];
var autocomplete;
var defaultLatLng = new plugin.google.maps.LatLng(34.0983425, -118.3267434); 
var myLatlng = new plugin.google.maps.LatLng(37.783259, -122.402708);

function initialize() {
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 17,
    //center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: plugin.google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    browserSupportFlag = true;
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      initialLocation = new plugin.google.maps.LatLng(position.coords
        .latitude, position.coords.longitude);
      map.setCenter(initialLocation);
  map.setZoom(16);
  var marker = new plugin.google.maps.Marker({
    position: initialLocation,
    title: "You are here!"
  });
  marker.setMap(map);
}, function() {
  handleNoGeolocation(browserSupportFlag);
});
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
    myOptions);
  places = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  plugin.google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'tilesloaded', tilesLoaded);
  autocomplete = new         plugin.google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById(
'autocomplete'));
  plugin.google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
showSelectedPlace();
  });
}
```

Comment: Hi tejas, i have tried adding the "plugins" before initializing, however the code no longer works in my browser. do i need to install a plugin first? sorry im no good at this :/ @TejasGhutukade

Answer (score 0):

At least

1. var defaultLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(34.0983425, -118.3267434); 
   var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.783259, -122.402708);

should be placed inside initialize()

2. center: myLatlng

shouldn't be commented out

3. There should be the following css styles

   html, body {
       height: 100%;
   }

   ## map {

   ```
   height: 100%;
   ```

   }

Comment: i tried step one, however the maps stopped loading completely in my broswer, i uncommented the myLatLng, however that didnt fix my mobile issue. ive already done step 3, any other ideas on what could be the issue? thanks.